# React Native Metro Unable to resolve module

Tags: javascript, react-native, import, node-modules, metro-bundler

In the process of updating React Native from `0.69.10` to `0.70.9`, I've updated Metro to `v0.72.3`

When running the App, I'm getting the error

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-gesture-handler from /path-to-project/index.js: react-native-gesture-handler could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../node_modules
  ../../../../node_modules
```

However, I've checked `node_modules` and found out that `node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler` exists

This problem does not only happen for `react-native-gesture-handler`. It also happens for `react-native-screens`, `redux-form` and so on, which leads me to think that it's a Metro resolution issue.

However, the path that Metro mentions that it tried to look at seems correct, so I'm not sure what could be the case here

Before the upgrade, everything was working as expected

## **What I've tried**

I've tried resetting cache when running the start script `react-native start --reset-cache` but it doesn't work

I've also tried to disable Hermes. Doesn't seem to be the case either

I've also cleared iOS and Android cache, clearing `node_modules` and re-installing everything, to no avail

I've also ensured that all metro packages are in the correct version `v0.72.3`

I've tried to clear cache via `rm -rf ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/metro-*`, and it doesn't work either

I've also tried updating metro to the latest version at `v0.76.4` by adding

```
  "resolutions": {
    "metro": "^0.76.4"
  },
```

But the same error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to got it working

```
// metro.config.js

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: [
      ... other stuff
      'json' // <=== add this
    ]
  },
};
```

Reason being that there is a breaking change in v0.72.0 release ([here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/releases/tag/v0.72.0))

```
[Breaking] .json files will no longer be implicitly resolved if removed from resolver.sourceExts (https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/a3dc30aa0d54d65d6dbd426662f59b0ec398a612)
```

The resolver algorithm checks for each package's `package.json` to resolve to the file being put in `main`. Under the hood, it uses `this._hasteFS.exists(packageJsonPath)`

Full investigation [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/988)

Since `context.doesFileExist` checks for `package.json` (which is a json file), we will need to explicitly add `json` to `resolver.sourceExts`